# loglog plots with inverted x_axis in python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I want to make a figure which has similar axis to the example below. I know I could use loglog plot. But in this example, the step-size (x-axis) decreases when you go farther to the right.

How could I do this in python (using matplotlib)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly the invert_xaxis call is what you are looking for. As follows:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_axes()
ax.invert_xaxis()
```

Link: http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes